# How to move posts of a specific category into a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I want to move many posts which have more than one category into the custom post type.
Currently all posts are added into the posts section but i want to move all posts into my custom post type section my site is http://www.edarabia.com/

I want to move all school posts in the schools custom post type and all universities posts into the universities custom posts type and same for nurseries.
Please guide me how it can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write SQL query changing the post_type field of posts or pages from "post" to "school" (assuming school is a custom post type name) and also map categories and tags.

Alternatively you can try plugins:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-post-types/

Answer (score 0):

The following update will change all posts types to `school` for posts that are in the category with ID `1` :

```
UPDATE
    wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
SET
    wp_posts.post_type = 'school'
WHERE
    wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 1
```